# Converting a string to a function

Tags: lua

In Lua, you can convert a function to a string where it returns what appears to be an address

```
print(print)
function: 0x41a360
```

Is it possible to do the reverse? e.g.

```
local aliasPrint = function: 0x41a360
aliasPrint("Hello, World!")
Hello, World!
```

I looked around online for a solution, but my google-fu may be lacking.

Comment: You can simply do `aliasPrint=print`. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you are not converting a function to a string. `string.dump` does that in limited cases. And, `load` is the inverse.

```
local function f()
    print("I'm a function")
end

local d = string.dump(f)
print(string.format("%q", d))

local g = load(d);
g()
```

---

As to your approach, I can only ask, "Why?"

`tostring` is a function that gives a notional representation of an object with essential information. In many cases, (functions and tables), uniqueness is an essential property. So, `tostring` includes that in its representation. Many languages have something similar but don't always show uniqueness. (Some do show more properties in a debugger.)

Comment: Great! I noticed some system functions are unable to be dumped, is there a way to check this BEFORE you dump (i.e. in a loop) them as to prevent errors? As to the why, it's just a question I had as I was working my way through some basic Lua.

Comment: You can call [debug.getinfo](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-debug.getinfo) first. If the `what` field is "C", the function can't be dumped. If the `nups` field is > 0, see [load](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-load).

Answer (score 0):

Lua does not have reflection, but the function names are stored as string in memory as a "key". You can achieve in a similar way

```
local aliasPrint = _ENV["print"]
aliasPrint("Hello, World!")
```

output:

```
Hello, World!
```

`_ENV` is the lookup table of the running environment of Lua global variables (for Lua v5.1-, use `_env` instead)

If you are using a function in an object, just substitude `_ENV["print"]` by `table_or_object["function_name"]`.

Comment: You make some good points but your explanation could lead to misunderstanding. Functions, like all other values, do not have names. You are describing global variables and table fields. Variables have names. Table fields have keys, which could be considered names, particularly if they are strings that are valid identifiers.

Comment: As for reflection, I'd call `pairs` and `debug.getinfo` reflection.